# LSTM Layer producing same outputs for different sequences

Tags: nlp, lstm, multilabel-classification

Currently I try to train on a multi-label language task with imbalanced class distribution. I have the following model, where I removed some of the feed forward layers to decrease factors in the chain of gradients.

Since the outputs are extremely weird during inference time (i.e. every prediction is class 1 of 32 and no others), I started to check the layers, esp. the LSTM layer to see if any inconsistencies occur.

First let me share my model-architecture with you.

```
class Bi_RNN(nn.Module):
    """"
    Embedding Dim 300
    """
    def __init__(self, hidden_dim_lstm, in_2_dim, in_3_dim, in_4_dim, input_dim=300, output_dim=32, num_layers=1, batch_size=1):
        super(Bi_RNN, self).__init__()
        
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim_lstm*2*num_layers
        self.hidden_dim_lstm = hidden_dim_lstm
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.in_2_dim = in_2_dim
        self.in_3_dim = in_3_dim
        self.in_4_dim = in_4_dim
        self.act = nn.PReLU()

        # Define the LSTM layer
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(self.input_dim, self.hidden_dim_lstm, self.num_layers, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)

        # Define the FFN
        self.linear_layer_1 = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, self.in_4_dim)
        self.linear_layer_last = nn.Linear(self.in_4_dim, output_dim)  
        
    def init_hidden(self):
        # This is what we'll initialise our hidden state as
        device = next(self.parameters()).device.type
        return (torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim//2).to(device),
                torch.zeros(self.num_layers*2, self.batch_size, self.hidden_dim//2).to(device))
    
    def forward(self, input):
        lstm_out, self.hidden = self.lstm(input, self.init_hidden())
        h_n, c_n = self.hidden
        c_n_merged = c_n.reshape(self.batch_size, -1)
  
        layer_1_out = self.act(self.linear_layer_1(c_n_merged))
        out = self.linear_layer_last(layer_1_out)
        out = torch.sigmoid(out)

        return out
```

This is the model state after training. Consider the following inputs `x` each with shape `torch.Size([7484, 300])` (it's actually a batch with `torch.Size([64, 7484, 300])`).

x_1 looks like this

```
tensor([[-0.1113,  0.1436,  0.1895,  ...,  0.0342,  0.1602, -0.2500],
         [ 0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000,  ...,  0.0000,  0.0000,  0.0000],
         [-0.2910,  0.1787,  0.0500,  ..., -0.0228,  0.1177,  0.3535],
         ...
```

x_2 looks like this

```
tensor([[ 0.1250,  0.0266, -0.0272,  ..., -0.0864, -0.1621, -0.0337],
         [ 0.0070, -0.0732,  0.1719,  ...,  0.0112,  0.1641,  0.1069],
         [ 0.0762,  0.0820, -0.1118,  ..., -0.0942, -0.0684,  0.2266],
         ...
```

So when getting the LSTM out of the model and passing these vectors (as a batch) into the LSTM, the hidden states `c_n, h_n` with shape `torch.Size([800])` are identical (most of them are for the complete batch)

The `c_n` look like this

```
tensor([[-0.1549,  0.0412, -0.0041,  ..., -0.1105, -0.0761,  0.0696],
        [-0.1549,  0.0412, -0.0041,  ..., -0.1105, -0.0761,  0.0696]],
```

and the `h_n` look like this

```
tensor([[-0.0746,  0.0206, -0.0020,  ..., -0.0547, -0.0372,  0.0344],
        [-0.0746,  0.0206, -0.0020,  ..., -0.0547, -0.0372,  0.0344]],
```

I don't understand how this is happening and I would be very grateful if somebody can point out what my misconception is.

Q: How can I adjust my model, such that it properly produces context vectors on input sequences with different output?
Q: Is there an error in coding in my model, such that I provoke this behavior?

I am sorry in advance if there are any rather stupid mistakes.

Thanks